# Facebook FQL Latests Photos of my friends

Tags: ios, facebook, request, facebook-fql, photos

I want to have the list of my friends' latests photos since last week
To have this solution I do this request in FQL :

```
 SELECT src_big ,owner,created FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN

(SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner IN

(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) 
AND modified_major > 1359158400) AND created > 1359158400 ORDER BY created DESC
```

It's working but when I test my application (iOS) with a Facebook account which has more than 100 friends => I don't have all the latest photos

Some friends are not taken into account...

I don't have any idea to find a solution

Do you have any idea to have all the latests photos of my friends since the last week ?

Thanks for your help , I'm very disappointed...